# What is benefit of this constructor definition

Tags: c++, class, constructor, coding-style

I was just going through random pages on Cprogramming.com and noticed the [Constructors and Destructors](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/constructor_destructor_ordering.html) tutorial/example page. They have used the following method of defining a constructor:

```cpp
class String
{
    private:
        char *str;
        int size;
    public:
        String() : str(NULL), size(0) { }  // <- This statement
        String(int size) : str(NULL), size(size) {  // <- And this one
            str = new char[size];
        }
}
```

I've been using the good old fashioned definition of constructors with the magic `this` pointer:

```cpp
String() { 
    this->str = NULL;
    this->size = 0;
}
String(int size) {
    this->size = size;
    this->str = new char[size];
}
```

Is there any added benefit in the first declaration beside the obvious smaller code (less number of lines)?

**PS:** It has been quite a few years since I last did write something in C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are [constructor initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html), and for *fundamental types* there is no difference with respect to the form you are used to, which is based on *assignment* rather than initialization.

However, for user-defined types there might be a difference in terms of performance (and semantics perhaps) between:

1. default-constructing an object and *then* assigning a value to it, and
2. directly initializing it with that value.

Also, you do not have a choice for those types that are not default-constructible other than using a member initialization list to initialize them, and you do not have a choice for `const` and reference members either, that must be initialized immediately.

Answer (score 1):

i was like you, with the back old collage knowledge this usage seems weird. But then understand that by using this technique, custom class implementations give better performance on runtime. And [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OioZ78jnlM) is a long explanation about initiatization lists from the father of C++.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing objects in C++ is done in three steps:

1. Memory is aquired
2. Member variables are initialized
3. The constructor is executed.

The constructor definition `String() : str(NULL), size(0) {}` assigns the proper value to the variables in step 2.

The constructor definition `String() { this->str = NULL; this->size = 0; }` does this in step 3. Step 2 is, however, executed nevertheless. So this kind of assigning the proper value to the member variables is less efficient.